# It it possible to have ARR working without a matching service/website on the ARR machine itself?

Tags: iis, arr

I am not sure if I am missing something, but I'd really like to have it work like a routing rules table.

However it appears that if I have a service on a farm machine, then the same service should expose the same endpoints on the ARR machine.

I am not sure why thats really needed or what am doing wrong.
Its rather silly. So if I have farm with some application, first of all it has to be deployed to ARR machine, otherwise I get all kinds of 503, 500, 404 etc errors due to services/webpages not being available on the machine where ARR is setup.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, ensure that the "proxy" feature is enabled...

**IIS Home -> Application Request Routing -> Server Proxy Settings -> Enable Proxy**

[image: ARR Enable Proxy]

Then add rewrite rules to web.config as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="AppProxy1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="app1/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://appserver:8080/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="AppProxy2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="app2/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://appserver:8081/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <!-- add more apps here -->
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Make sure that the rewrite rules contain absolute URLs, (including http://).  This key step signals ARR to run in "proxy" mode.

Additionally, you may need to rewrite outbound HTML links depending on your configuring.  More information on that and using ARR as a reverse proxy in general can be found here:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

But the basic idea is listed above.

Comment: Hi. Proxy is enabled of course. Maybe I do not understand exactly what stopProcesing does here, could you elaborate its role? I've read that article before, and indeed it appears that their scenario is not built on top of working website on ARR machine, which is key of my question here.

Comment: I'll award bounty so it doesn't burn away of course. It doesn't solve the problem immediately though.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty :) I still hope to be of some assistance here. All that "stopProcessing" does is prevent URLRewrite from reading any more rules once one is matched. For simplicity sake, try adding a rule as follows to your localhost `<rule name="AppHarbor" stopProcessing="true"><match url="appharbor/(.*)" /><action type="Rewrite" url="https://appharbor.com/{R:1}" /></rule>`, then load the following URL in your browser (http://localhost/appharbor/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png). This should demonstrate ARR fetching content from a server other than the server where ARR is installed.

Comment: Are you able to post the web.config file for the ARR site you are configuring?  It might be helpful to see.